# How is echoing a var_dump valid?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have set E_ALL for error_reporting,

today when i was reviewing my code, i saw something like:

```
$test = '';
echo var_dump($test);
```

while it doesn't cause any problem as far as i see, i was curious how is this valid? error_reporting didn't show anything.

Will leaving it like that harm anything?

### Edit:

It's not about being null, the following is okay too:

```
$test = array('test');
echo var_dump($test);
```

Comment: var_dump returns nothing, it's the same as echoing NULL!

Comment: No, his value is an empty string. It isn't NULL.

Comment: Please see my edit, its not about being null

Comment: I didn't say his value is null, I said var_dump  returns null !

Comment: Wade doesn't know the difference between *displaying* a value and *returning* a value.

Comment: Agreed @GolezTrol Heck, even `<?php //` is valid in PHP, wondering if they know about that too ;-) plus, won't even throw an error.

Comment: `var_dump('');` is the equivalent of `$test = '';
echo var_dump($test);` both being valid statements. Since var_dump expects a parameter and since you've got something "assigned" to `$test`, PHP says it's valid. Doing `$test = ';` however would be invalid, since there is no closing quote. Either `'` or `"` are valid statement wrappers when started/opened and ended/closed. You can even  var_dump an empty constant `define("CONSTANT", ""); var_dump(CONSTANT);` which is the same as your first example.

Comment: Here, want to see something else that's really freaky? Try this out for size `define("HH", "HH1");

define("CONSTANT", HH); echo CONSTANT;` - Guess what that will print. Yeah, it's valid.

Comment: @GolezTrol Snark comments aren't productive here on SO, with 66k rep you should know that. The OP wasn't as clear, before his first edit. As you can see in my (edited) answer, my example is more clear than yours. EVERY function returns something, even **if you don't explicitly tell it to return a value**, it returns `null` on it's own. I have been programming for 15 years, OOP MVC, and about 10 languages.. and I don't know about returning vs displaying?

Comment: @WadeShuler It was based on your additional answer, as well as your comment to my answer in which you say *"which **returns** that $test is an empty string"*. So apart from any semantic discussion whether `null` would be considered a value or not (after all, those null functions are documented as void functions), I think I had a strong case for my comment. That aside, I didn't intend to be snarky, and I apologize for that. I just intended to prevent that the misconception about var_dump's return value would lead to a big discussion. Then, unfortunately, Fred -ii- came along... ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol I never put much thought into var_dump, it just works.. I completely get how it works, as my answer illustrates. I thought OP was hung up on it dumping an empty string, that there was nothin to dump. I myself put echo before var_dump because I don't write functions that echo, just returns data like they should. So that didn't stand out to me, it looked normal..

Comment: PS: I think Fred got a little carried away with his overuse of examples :p Constant prints HH1.

Comment: Any reason for downvote? should we not ask such questions here?

Comment: @WadeShuler hehe, well Golez did write *"It's a bit weird but PHP..."*, so I took it one step beyond, demonstrating just how much more weirder PHP can be. If it's valid, it works ;-) this just goes to show how PHP is a loosely-typed language.

Comment: Voted to reopen: The question has only one distinct (short) answer that is correct. The answer is not open for interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

var_dump doesn't return anything, so you're just echoing nothing. It's a bit weird but PHP just accepts this, but that's because void functions actually return `null` in PHP. `null` (meaning 'nothing') can be assigned to a variable and can be echoed as well. If you echo `null`, there is no output.

So while the code is valid, it doesn't *do* anything. It just lets var_dump echo its own output, but the explicit `echo` keyword doesn't add any value.

To give another example, the same happens when you do this with your own function. For instance, if someone would misinterpret a function, you could see code like this:

```
// Function has no return value but echoes all by itself.
function outputGreeting() {
  echo 'hello world';
}

// User thought function would return the value, and uses an obsolete echo.
echo outputGreeting();
```

The code echoes the function result (which is void), and still the code seems to work.

Comment: Your not echoing nothing.. Your echoing the result of var_dump, which returns that $test is an empty string.

Comment: That is not true. var_dump doesn't *return* anything. It just echoes some information. The return value is void, and echoing void is acceptable in PHP and results in nothing being outputted. Your misconception is exacly what my code snippet is about.

Comment: The result of var_dump() is null (even though the function doesn't return a value), in which var_dump echos the result on it's own. It's like: `echo null; var_dump($val);` - I initially thought he was talking about the string being empty.

Comment: I thought var_dump echos something, and `echoing an echo` seemed weird to me, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I originally thought you were talking about the string being empty.

var_dump() itself does NOT explicitly return anything, that doesn't mean it isn't anything though, or that nothing is returned from the function. The value that var_dump() returns, is `null`, just like every function that doesn't return a value.

This is what your doing:

```
$val = '';
echo null;
var_dump($val);
```

Lets show it this way, with our own function:

```
function myfunc() {
    // I do nothing
}

$val = myfunc();
var_dump($val);  // <-- prints 'null' to the screen
```

This proves that our own function (and var_dump() itself) returns `null`.

Comment: This is not the point. It's about the echo. `var_dump` doesn't return whether the string is empty. var_dump just outputs information and returns nothing (void). The documentation you linked to is clear on that.

Comment: @GolezTrol - updated to show how a function returns null when no return value is set. I think this is a better representation of what the OP is talking about.